# Changing "order" of monitors in LXDE/LXPanel

Tags: fedora, monitors, lxde

I have a laptop and an external HDMI monitor.  I have determined how to use `arandr` to align and rotate the display to a point where I am happy, have ticked the "Primary" option for the laptop screen (LVDS-1) and ticked the "Active" option for both screens (LVDS-1 and HDMI-1-1).

I want the main LXDE desktop and LXPanel taskbar to be on the laptop at all times.  However, when the HDMI monitor is plugged in, both the taskbar and desktop icons move across to the HDMI screen.

In the LXPanel panel settings, there is a dropdown for which monitor you want the LXPanel to be displayed on, with *All*, *1* and *2* being the options.  If I set this to *2*, the LXPanel will live on the laptop screen, but the desktop icons remain on the HDMI.

If I unplug the HDMI, the LXPanel disappears.  I presume this is because the monitor ID reverts to *1*, while the LXPanel is configured to live on *2*.

If I'm right about that, then I am looking for a way to ensure that the laptop screen is always monitor *1*, and that the HDMI (if plugged in) is monitor *2*.  Note that I have already set "Primary" in `arandr` and both this and `xrandr` state that LVDS-1 is the primary.

Any ideas...?